# Working around LINQ 2 SQL Coalesce limitation

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, coalesce

I'm trying to convert an existing T-SQL query into a C# Linq2Sql query, but the generated T-SQL query makes a too deeply nested COALESCE chain. Is there a way of working around this without invoking dynamic T-SQL?

Consider a table in Sql Server along the following lines:

```
create table MyTable(id int, a int, b int, c int, d int)
```

Now this C# query:

```
from t in MyTable select new { id = id, val = t.a ?? t.b ?? t.c ?? t.d };
```

This results in the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[id] AS [id], COALESCE([t0].[a],COALESCE([t0].[b],COALESCE([t0].[c],[t0].[d]))) AS [val]
FROM [Case] AS [t0]
```

As you can see, Linq2Sql abuses the coalesce (??) operator - it keeps nesting each operation as an internal and separate Coalesce(...), essentially treating it like IsNull(...) which only takes two parameters.

The problem is that SQL Server has a limit of how deeply such coalesce may be nested (10 levels), and my query has significantly more parameters. This means my query crashes at runtime with the following error:

> SqlException: Case expressions may only be nested to level 10.

The original T-SQL query simply stacks the parameters normally, such as: COALESCE(a, b, c, d, e, f ,g ...) but I can't find a way to force Linq2Sql to do the same. Any help or tip would be appreciated!

Of course, the actual query involves tons of tables and joins, the above pseudo code is for illustration only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
from t in MyTable select new { id = id, val = (t.a ?? t.b) ?? (t.c ?? t.d) };
```

it generates

```
COALESCE(COALESCE([t0].[a],[t0].[b]),COALESCE([t0].[c],[t0].[d]))
```

so it should scale up to 1024 columns. But I admit it is weird...

Comment: Great, that works as a solution for now! Setting them up in pairs, and then in recursive pairs, keeps me under the limit. I did experiment a bit with parentheses at first too, but the output was so messy (and still beyond the limit) that I didn't notice the difference.Thanks!